# CLIPS: check more than one fact

Tags: clips

Let's consider the next trivial template:

```
(deftemplate person (ssn ?s))
```

I want to check that, if a person "is registered", there are no other person with same `ssn`, however, I've tried with something like:

```
(defrule repeated-person
     (person (ssn ?s1))
     (person (ssn ?s2))
     (test (= ?s1 ?s2))
  =>
     (printout t "No, no, no..." clrf))
```

or even,

```
(defrule repeated-person
     (person (ssn ?s))
     (person (ssn ?s))
  =>
     (printout t "No, no, no..." clrf))
```

but it didn't work.

How can I accomplish something like that?

Answer (score 1):

By default, you can't create duplicates of facts:

```
         CLIPS (6.31 2/3/18)
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate person
   (slot SSN))
CLIPS> (assert (person (SSN 123-45-6789)))
<Fact-1>
CLIPS> (facts)
f-0     (initial-fact)
f-1     (person (SSN 123-45-6789))
For a total of 2 facts.
CLIPS> (assert (person (SSN 123-45-6789)))
FALSE
CLIPS> (facts)
f-0     (initial-fact)
f-1     (person (SSN 123-45-6789))
For a total of 2 facts.
CLIPS>
```

You can change this behavior using the set-fact-duplication function:

```
CLIPS> (set-fact-duplication TRUE)
FALSE
CLIPS> (assert (person (SSN 123-45-6789)))
<Fact-2>
CLIPS> (facts)
f-0     (initial-fact)
f-1     (person (SSN 123-45-6789))
f-2     (person (SSN 123-45-6789))
For a total of 3 facts.
CLIPS>
```

You can then write a rule which checks to see if there are two different facts with the same SSN:

```
CLIPS> 
(defrule repeated-person
   ?f1 <- (person (SSN ?ss))
   ?f2 <- (person (SSN ?ss))
   (test (< (fact-index ?f1) (fact-index ?f2)))
   =>
   (printout t "Duplicated SSN " ?ss crlf))
CLIPS> (agenda)
0      repeated-person: f-1,f-2
For a total of 1 activation.
CLIPS>
```

Since each fact has a unique fact index, the comparison in the test conditional element ensures that the facts matching the first and second patterns are not the same.

If we add another person with an identical SSN, we'll get multiple activations of the rule:

```
CLIPS> (assert (person (SSN 123-45-6789)))
<Fact-3>
CLIPS> (agenda)
0      repeated-person: f-1,f-3
0      repeated-person: f-2,f-3
0      repeated-person: f-1,f-2
For a total of 3 activations.
CLIPS>
```

We can dynamically assign a unique id to each created fact which allows to create "duplicate" facts even when facts duplication is disabled:

```
CLIPS> (clear)
CLIPS> (set-fact-duplication FALSE)
TRUE
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate person
   (slot id (default-dynamic (gensym*)))
   (slot SSN))
CLIPS> (assert (person (SSN 123-45-6789)))
<Fact-1>
CLIPS> (assert (person (SSN 123-45-6789)))
<Fact-2>
CLIPS> (assert (person (SSN 123-45-6789)))
<Fact-3>
CLIPS> (facts)
f-0     (initial-fact)
f-1     (person (id gen1) (SSN 123-45-6789))
f-2     (person (id gen2) (SSN 123-45-6789))
f-3     (person (id gen3) (SSN 123-45-6789))
For a total of 4 facts.
CLIPS>
```

We can then create a rule which prints a single message regardless of the number of people with the same SSN:

```
CLIPS> 
(defrule repeated-person
   (person (id ?id) (SSN ?ssn))
   (not (person (id ?id2&:(< (str-compare ?id2 ?id) 0)) (SSN ?ssn)))
   (exists (person (id ~?id) (SSN ?ssn)))
   =>
   (printout t "Duplicated SSN " ?ssn crlf))
CLIPS> (agenda)
0      repeated-person: f-1,*,*
For a total of 1 activation.
CLIPS> (run)
Duplicated SSN 123-45-6789
CLIPS>
```